# jquery to traverse the div and get its span details

Tags: jquery

I have a html page as below:

```
<div id="test1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="234">ABKO</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="1234">ABKO2</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="2634">ABKO3</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div>
<div id="test2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="233">ABKOw</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="1236">ABKOc</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="2635">ABKOv</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div>
```

How can i get all the span details between  using jQuery? 
eg if i consider first div=test1 then i want all the soan with their ID and text 
as
div -> test1
    Span => id 233 && ABKO
    Span => id 1234 && ABKO2
    Span => id 22634 && ABKO3

Comment: It is not valid HTML to start an ID with a number. It must start with a letter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can iterate through all the `<span>` elements like so:

```
$('div span').each(function(){
    var $span = $(this);

    var divId = $span.closest('div').attr('id');
    var spanId = $span.attr('id');
    var spanTxt = $span.text()

    // do something with the above
});
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/kRRp6/1/).

What this is doing is building a list of span elements that are nested in a div ([CSS selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) `div span`).  It then iterates over this list using the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

Within each iteration `$(this)` refers to the matched span element.  We capture a reference in the `$span` variable so we don't keep recreating the same jQuery object.

We then use the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find the span's first ancestor that matches the given selector (`div`).  This gets our parent div.

Finally [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) gets the ID attribute and text values .

Answer (score 7):

You can find an element by Id with something like `$('#test1')`. You can find elements by tag with `$('span')` or `$('div')`.

If you want to find all the spans belonging to "test1":

`$('#test1').find('span')`

or

`$('#test1 span')`

You can iterate over a collection of elements with `each()`:

```
$('#test1').find('span').each(function() { 
    var id = this.id;
    var value = $(this).html();
    // do whatever...
});
```

Hopefully you can work the rest out yourself from this.