# Traversing on each span under table > tr > td > div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to traverse on each span under `table > tr > td > div` ?

I would like to hide those `span` elements once click on the anchor tag that beneath the same `tr` level.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt15199/L1j9psz6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $('#table td div span').each(function(){
            var $span = $(this);
            $(this).siblings().hide();
            var spanattr = $span.attr('class');
            alert(spanattr);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdspan">
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="spanelem">First</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdspan">
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="spanelem">Second</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdspan">
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="spanelem">3rd</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <br>
</table>
<span id="text"></span>
```

I already searched for other questions and used the provided solution such as below link but I'm not able to figure it out.

[jquery to traverse the div and get its span details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408030/jquery-to-traverse-the-div-and-get-its-span-details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need for loops there.

Simply `.find()` span with class `.spanelem` in a closest `<tr>` parent of the clicked element:

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.spanelem').hide();
    // Or using selector context (.find() equivalent but a bit shorter)
    // $('.spanelem', $(this).closest('tr')).hide();
});
```

<s>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rpb0m5w/)</s> [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9sew7xw3/)

---

References:

- [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context)

Comment: Since he had an alert for each span broadcasting its class, I wasn't sure whether that meant he didn't always know in the future what that class was going to be...

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to hide the spans themselves?  You are hiding their siblings, and since they are the only children of their parent `div`, there is nothing else to hide.  If you want to hide the spans themselves, then just change

```
$(this).siblings().hide();
```

to

```
$(this).hide();
```

If you have multiple rows, then you can just crawl up the tree from the `.hide` button that was clicked to its ancestor row, then find all the spans within that row.  You may want to search on a particular class, or all spans, but I don't know for sure how you identify which elements you want to hide.

Something like

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('span').each(function() {
```

Updated JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fk9jgrLx/4/

Comment: Can you tell me also how to do this on a table that data coming from database? I mean if there are multiple table row.

Comment: I want to hide only the span element on a tr wherein I click the anchor. Above works but if there are multiple tables rows, it hides all rows with span.

Comment: I added something that will hide all spans for the given row only, but you can tweak the selector in the `find` to locate elements however you would like (by element type or perhaps class instead).

Answer (score 0):

If your table structure is as in provided example, and if you will have multiple rows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('span').hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L1j9psz6/1/ - remove all spans from row...